# What is the SQL Server equivalent for Oracle character set AL32UTF8?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, datatypes, collation, azure-sql-managed-instance

While porting data from oracle to Azure sql database I am facing the following issue where, empty data in Oracle is converted as ➞➞➞ in SQL Server

Pic1: Data as in Oracle DB;

[image: Screenshot data of Oracle Database]

Pic2: Data as in Sql server DB;

[image: Screenshot data of SQL Server Database]

Pic3: Data when pasted in Notepad++.

[image: Screenshot of the oracle data when pasted in Notepad++]

The character set in Oracle is `AL32UTF8` and that of target SQL Server database is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. I have tried changing the datatype to `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` and changing the collation of the column to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS`, but no solution. What is the reason for this difference and is there any solution?

Comment: Use [rawtohex](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions131.htm#SQLRF00692) and [dump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm#SQLRF00635) in Oracle to see if the "empty" column contains non-printable characters.

Comment: Check the content in the Oracle database with `select dump(name, 1016) from table where ...` to see what is really stored in there.

Answer (score 2):

`NVARCHAR` is always UTF-16.

You can try `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` with a `VARCHAR` column, but that doesn't look like an encoding problem. It really shouldn't matter what the source encoding / collation was as long as you correctly indicate the encoding used to transfer the data.

Either way, those 3 bytes / characters could be a bug in the import tool/process or the export tool/process. How are you transferring the data? If the image you are showing from Notepad++ is from the file being used to migrate the data and the field is supposed to be empty, either the export messed up, or perhaps the field in Oracle is not truly empty.

Comment: I tried Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 with varchar, and yeah it didnt work. The column in oracle DB is actually 'not null', so it is not truly empty, but if i copy paste in sql developer i could see three empty space only and we are porting this data using Oracle Golden Gate.

Comment: @Venkat By definition, a space is not "empty" ;-).Empty can only mean `NULL` or for strings, an empty string (i.e. having 0 characters). Can you paste those into Notepad++, then hit `Control-A`, go to **Plugins** menu, select **Converter** then **ASCII -> HEX** ? You should see "1A", which is character 26, which you can get from either `Control-Z` or while holding down `ALT` key, type `026` on keypad (in Notepad++ , not in a browser).

Comment: My bad, yeah, space is not empty, Thanks a lot for the explanation. So , after going through your explanation, I tried the following  'SELECT RAWTOHEX(name) "name_hex"
   FROM <Table_Name>' as you said the output was '1A1A1A',  Also we are porting data via OGG, how to resolve this issue at sql server? can you let me know/or guide me to any link to understand more about this? Thanks a ton again.

Comment: @Venkat First execute the following to see what's actually in that column: `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(10), [name]) FROM dbo.table_name;`. Is it `0x1A1A1A`? If yes, then there's no issue to resolve as the data in SQL Server is the same as it was in Oracle, correct? If not, then we need to figure out why not.

Comment: @Venkat Also, I suppose in either case you should probably choose the desired datatype and collation now. If you go with UTF-8, you should also choose that as the DB's default collation, use only `VARCHAR` for strings (no `NVARCHAR`), and only use `_UTF8` collations. For a detailed look at various pros and cons of UTF-8 in SQL Server, please see: https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/09/28/native-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-savior-false-prophet-or-both/

Comment: from the above query the output is as expected: 0x1A1A1A. I went through the link which you have provided(not completely yet). One main point from the link which caught my eye was: 'This means that a VARCHAR(20) column for a first or last name is no longer guaranteed to always store up to 20 characters. As UTF-8, it will now store anywhere from 5 to 20 characters, depending on how many bytes each character requires', afraid this might create inconsistency. Secondly, Rather than setting it as default DB collation, can we change for a column alone and check this?

Comment: .@Solomon I also tried the same, altering the collation of name column alone to 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8', but no positive result though

Comment: @Venkat Good to know that the data is the same in both source and destination. Regarding the max size of VARCHAR columns/variables: yes, they're expressed in bytes, not characters. But, that's how most DBs are, and even those that allow for expressing the max size in characters should still end up having the same physical limitation in the end (meaning, saying `VARCHAR(20 characters)` is still 80 bytes, same as using `VARCHAR(80)` ). You _can_ do per-column for UTF-8, but as I explain in that post, that can open you up to potential problems. Finally, I'm not sure what your last message means.

Comment: the issue was with the data porting via OGG, character mapping for special characters and other language characters was not done. The issue is resolved now, Thanks for all your inputs

Comment: @Venkat Thanks for mentioning that. Can you please provide a little more detail, at the very least to help others that might run into this. At the moment, it's very unclear what the problem is, or that there is even a problem in the first place, given that the data is the same on both sides. The information provided so far does not indicate an encoding problem. So perhaps post an answer that explains how you fixed it and what the data looks like now that it is deemed "correct" at the destination. Thanks!